Second instance of a class suppresses/deletes the first one in my Python program
I am creating the Pong game using the Turtle module in Python. So far, I have one file for the paddles (the bars that players control to hit the ball) called paddles.py and a second file for the main gameplay control called game.py. I still plan on making a file for the ball and another for score-keeping.
In my paddles file, I create a Paddle class using the Turtle class. It doesn't exactly inherit from Turtle, but instead creates several Turtle instances inside each Paddle. I made a condition inside the __init__ of Paddle which sets a "left" paddle to the left and a "right" paddle to the right. Then I import the Paddle file to game.py and create a left_pad and a right_pad as follows:
left_pad = Paddle("left")
right_pad = Paddle("right")

On running the game.py file, the left_pad appears briefly then disappears, then only the right_pad is actually showing on the screen.

The shape is correct, the positioning is correct, but the left_pad is simply not there.
Here is the code for paddles.py (for now I am not worried about the moving functions):
from turtle import Turtle

class Paddle:
    side = ""
    paddle = [Turtle(shape="square") for i in range(4)]
    paddle_bottom = -30
    paddle_range = []


    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
        self.paddle_range = [self.paddle[0].screen.canvheight-10, -self.paddle[0].screen.canvheight+10]

        for box in range(len(self.paddle)):
            self.paddle[box].penup()

        # Set to middle height
        for box in range(len(self.paddle)):
            self.paddle[box].sety(self.paddle_bottom + 20*box)
        
        # Set to sides
        if side == "left":
            for box in range(len(self.paddle)):
                self.paddle[box].setx((-self.paddle[0].screen.canvwidth / 2) + 20)
        else:
            for box in range(len(self.paddle)):
                self.paddle[box].setx((self.paddle[0].screen.canvwidth / 2) - 20)


    def move():
        global paddle
        for box in len(range(paddle)):
            paddle[box].forward(1)
        paddle[0].screen.update()


    def move_up():
        global paddle_range
        global move
        for box in len(range(paddle)):
            paddle[box].setheading(90)
        while paddle[-1].ycor() < paddle_range[0]:
            move()


    def move_down():
        for box in len(range(paddle)):
            paddle[box].setheading(270)
        while paddle[0].ycor() > paddle_range[1]:
            move()


    if side == "left":
        paddle[0].screen.onkey(key="w", fun=move_up)
        paddle[0].screen.onkey(key="s", fun=move_down)
    else:
        paddle[0].screen.onkey(key="Up", fun=move_up)
        paddle[0].screen.onkey(key="Down", fun=move_down)

and the game.py:
from turtle import Screen
from paddles import Paddle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("beige")
screen.title("Pong!")
screen.setup(width=820, height=620)
screen.screensize(canvwidth=800, canvheight=600)
screen.tracer(0)
screen.listen()


left_pad = Paddle("left")
screen.update()
right_pad = Paddle("right")
screen.update()


screen.exitonclick()


There's only one paddle list which is shared and manipulated by both instances.

Also stop doing for .. in range(len(..)) (and most certainly len(range(...))). Use for paddle in self.paddle: paddle.penup().

class Paddle should have only one paddle - Turtle(shape="square") - and work only with own paddle. And it may need to get keys 'w' 's' as arguments to work only with these keys left_pad = Paddle("left", "w", "s"). And if you keep many Turtle(shape="square") in one class then it shouldn't have name Paddles but Paddles (with s) or even better PaddlesManager but this code would need to use move(paddle_number) to move only one paddle when you press keys.

I don't know how you can run this code if there are missing self in some places - it should raise error.

Are you taking a particular class, online course, or where is this material coming from? I answered a similar question last week where someone was trying to make pong using a class with global instead of instance variables: Why is the bat/board not moving up or down in the Pong Game, when the screen.listen() is called using the Turtle module in Python?. See the code in that link for a Pong design that doesn't share state between instances.

paddle = [Turtle(shape="square") for i in range(4)] should be in the constructor, on self.paddle, not a class property, and should simply be one turtle, not 4.

@deceze you're right about the for loop, I did it out of habit since regular list items can't be edited using the simpler method, but i guess class instances will work just fine.

@ggorlen I understand the simpler method in which the task wask designed, however I wanted to have four sections for a reason, which is that if the ball hits one of them, it will fly off at a different angle, it was just my idea to put a twist on the task.

@furas would it simplify things if I created the moving functions within the __init__ instead of creating more arguments for each function?

@furas also would you point out where self is missing? my editor did raise errors and I fixed all that I could find, and it's not complaining anymore

@deceze I looked at the question which was suggested to close my question and they said that to avoid making two classes share an attribute, all attributes should be declared in the constructor. Is my understanding correct?

@ggorlen also yes, I'm taking a Udemy course that's quite popular called 100 Days of Code by Angela Yu. Not surprised there were already some questions about it here. Honestly I was fine until we started doing Turtle, I don't even like graphics or gamemaking so I just used the Pong lesson to practice classes mostly. And I did learn quite a few things so I'm happy with that :)

In the linked question, OP is also attempting to use global to share state rather than self instance properties. Many courses teach poor practices, so it's nice to see where the problems that show up here over and over are coming from.

This comment in particular is relevant here: "Basically never use global, for starters. It has no place in any program. It's used as a quick hack simplification for beginning programmers who are learning the ropes and haven't grasped parameters, class state and return values yet, but should be dropped completely after that."

Actually, the teacher warned that global should be used sparingly and with caution. but some people (myself included lol) get excited when they learn something and think they understand it fully. Until recently I though global only applied to functions, apparently it works inside classes too.

@ggorlen thanks for the tip, I'll definitely remember that. You were right in that beginner-level courses don't explain the full functionality of every new word immediately, I guess that's a bit of a problem but it wouldn't be beginner-friendly otherwise haha

all functions inside class should have first parameter self - like def move(self). And if you run other function from class then you also should use self - like self.move(). And if defined paddle in class then you should use self.paddle to access it in functions in class.

don't create inside __init__ but below __init__ as next function in class - and it will need self as first parameter, and you will execute it also using self. And it means def move(self), def move_up(self), def move_down(self). Inside __init__ you should use .onkey(...) and they should use self in self.paddle....onkey(...) and in fun=self.move_up

your code after my modifications: https://pastebin.com/m5BghQ0Q
